# Summary statistics (mean and standard error) of split plot nested design- using R

Tags: r, mean, descriptive-statistics, nested-data, split-plot

I have a study with a split plot design where every season (wet and dry) we sampled for 3 years at 8 sites. At each site (fixed factor), we have plots (nested within sites) and then we have subplots nested within plots. We sampled different variables within the subplots (random effect). We also have replicates (a and b) one of the variables (conductivity) but not the rest. To analyze the data Ive used LMER model, using the Kenward-Roger method. LMER models were followed by an anova and then pairwise comparisons with a Tukey’s Honestly Significant Difference (HSD) test when significant.

**I also want to do summary statistics to look at the mean at each site and season. My question is how should I be getting the mean? Because it is a split plot nested design, should I first get the means across subplots, the across plots within each site, season, and year, and then across years? Or can I get the aggregated mean? What would be most appropriate? Also, any good websites/books to read on this topic, specifically on getting means and standard errors on data like these would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!.**

This are the variable names that I have: Season Year Site Plot Subplot Replicate Salinity_ppt Conductivity Temperature_mean

And this is the mean calculator I have on R-program right now:

```r
summary_stats <- filtered_dataset %>%
group_by(Season, Site) %>%
summarise(
  Conductivity_mean = mean(Conductivity, na.rm = TRUE),
  Conductivity_strr = sd(Conductivity, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(sum(! 
    is.na(Conductivity))),
  Temperature_mean = mean(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
  Temperature_stderr = sd(Temperature, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(sum(!
    is.na(Temperature))),
  Salinity_mean = mean(Salinity, na.rm = TRUE),
  Salinity_stderr = sd(Salinity, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(sum(!
    is.na(Salinity)))
)
```